# Make json from angucomplete-alt

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can any one help me How i can push Angucomplele value in json.
I want to use angucomplete value to make array of Json. So that i can post on Api.
Can any tell me with working example

`<div angucomplete-alt id="e1" placeholder="Type Bldg Number Here"pause="100" maxlength="50"selected-object="selectedBuilding12" initial-value="{{build.BLDG_NBR}}"local-data="myBuilding" description-field="NAME"search-fields="BLDG_NBR" title-field="BLDG_NBR" minlength="4" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight" override-suggestions="true" >`

Comment: <div angucomplete-alt id="e1" placeholder="Type Bldg Number Here" pause="100" maxlength="50" selected-object="selectedBuilding12" initial-value="{{build.BLDG_NBR}}" local-data="myBuilding" description-field="NAME"
                                               search-fields="BLDG_NBR" title-field="BLDG_NBR" minlength="4" input-class="form-control form-control-small" match-class="highlight" override-suggestions="true" >

Comment: If you need to add additional information to your question then you can edit it instead of posting new information as comment.

Comment: Can you tell with example how you can edit it instead of posting new information??

Comment: You can use the _edit_ link under your question. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page to understand how the site works (you also get a badge for taking the tour).